# PSU recommendation for new casual gaming setup

Tags: gaming, power-supply

I'm looking for a PSU recommendation for a setup below:

- Corsair 650D chassis
- Intel i5 4690K CPU
- ASRock Extreme6 mobo
- Radeon R9 290 GPU
- 16GB RAM (2x 8GB)
- 1x SSD 256GB
- 1x 2TB SATA HDD
- 2x 1TB SATA HDD as RAID1

and to have some wiggle room to OC.

Price range below $200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brief calculation from a [power calculator](http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) puts that build at needing around 600W of power (I made some assumptions about memory type and number of fans, as well as optical drives).

In that case, I recommend [Corsair's AX760](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139042), [again](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/483/57). This is above what should be required, giving you room to expand your components at a later date.

- It also is 80 Plus Platinum certified
- It is fully modular (only use cables you need)
- It is quiet
- It has a 7 year warranty
- If the 760W is to close to the 600W you will need, it has a larger 860W version available for just a bit more.

It retails for $190, but is on sale on Newegg for $150 right now.

Comment: 860W is not too much to go for?

Comment: If you are not going to be doing any upgrades in the future, 860 is probably to much and the 760 will be fine. If you are planning major updates to the video card or more hard drives, the bigger PSU will be helpful

Comment: I think maybe 2nd Radeon in the future for the Crossfire with CPU upgrade and maybe additional HDD.

Comment: Got AX760 from NewEgg for $99

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I run the following config in my living room:

- Case: [RAIDMAX Element ATX-101BG](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811156313)
- Mobo: some mini-itx board, AsRock maybe?
- CPU: i5-4690
- GPU: [GTX 970 Reference](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814132038)
- SSD: 240GB Corsair GS
- HDD: Western Digital Black 2TB
- Fans: stock CPU fan, large fan at top of case
- Memory: 16GB @ 1866
- PSU: CORSAIR CX series CX500M

Using Kill-A-Watt meter, if my memory serves me right then I peaked around 350 watts when I tortured it with Prime95 and FurMark at the same time.

CPU: 90°C, GPU 80°C

I play Witcher 3 on max settings with hairworks set to 2xAA for hours on end.

CPU: 70°C, GPU 80°C

If I have a larger case then there would definitely be room for better cooling but I never intend to OC and Prime95 is a highly edge-case temperature scenario.

Idle temps, cool as a cucumber:

CPU: 35°C, GPU: 35°C